# Geometric Mean of Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation, error-propagation

I measure a series of $n$ objects `[O_1, O_2, O_3, ..., O_n]`. Because those measurements are quite hard to perform, I have quite a lot of measurement error and therefore I measured each object $r$ times to get a better estimate. The distributions of measurements are bounded between 0 and 1 (inclusive) but are not uniform. Might kinda look like a normal (but bounded) distribution, eventually skewed though. The standard deviation of the measurements for the objects `O_i` is $sd_i$.

I want to compute the geometric mean of the mean measurement of those objects

$$X = \left(\prod \bar O_i\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

, where $\bar O_i$ is the mean of the $r$ measurements of the object $O_i$.

**What is the standard deviation and the standard error of the geometric mean of these $n$ variables?**

Is the standard deviation of $X$ simply

$$sd_X = \left(\prod sd_i\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

and the standard error of $X$ ($se_X$) would simply be

$$se_X = \frac{\left(\prod sd_i\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{r}$$

Comment: Note: For practical purposes, most of the time (if not always) I will measure only 2 objects.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking the population is beta and that is why you are using the geometric mean. See Wikipedia 'beta distribution', especially under maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I am computing the geometric mean because this is the statistics I am interested in. Would take some time explain why I am interested in the geometric means of those objects. I am asking what the standard deviation (and standard error for the mean) of the geometric mean of the mean of $n$ objects, each measured $r$ times, where object $i$ has a standard deviation of $sd_i$. Does it make sense? Thanks for your comment

Comment: You seem to be taking geometric means with sample means as data. Haven't seen that before. I don't think your SD and SE are correct. Could always be wrong. MLE for beta uses geometric means and the Wikipedia article I mentioned has related dist'n theory that _may_ be useful. If all else fails, you could bootstrap the SD of your $X$s. With $rn$ obs. altogether, you should have enough data for a useful bootstrap. Question has only been up for an hour. Maybe better advice is forthcoming.

Comment: @Remi.b - Are all of these samples taken across the different objects independent of each other by assumption?

Comment: All measurements taken on `O_2` will be similar and all measurements on `O_2` will be similar. But the third measurements of object `O_1` and `O_2` are totally independent. Did I answer your question?